# Why does interpreter with JIT produce faster codes than the one without?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, interpreter, jit, jvm-hotspot

I'm still not clear about the concept of compiling byte codes into machine codes by a JIT compiler. I want to know why it produce faster codes v.s a non-JIT interpreter. Can somebody give me a good example on how this process is done?

Comment: Because executing native machine language is faster than executing bytecode. Bytecode is the "machine language" of a virtual machine, but it still ends up modifying real data in memory. JITting it allows native machine code to perform those same operations.

Comment: Can you give me a brief example on how this "modifying real data in memory" is done (JIT vs non-JIT) ?

Comment: Look at some disassembled bytecode to see the non-JIT version. Look at some assembly language to see the JIT version.

Comment: what commands do you use to get the non-JIT / JIT version in Java?

Comment: You don't get the JIT version (w/o some difficulty). `javap -c` disassembles a class file and shows the bytecode. Examples of assembly language are everywhere.

Answer (score 30):

Suppose you have a loop which needs to be executed a million times.

A "true" interpreter needs to look at the bytecode of this on each iteration of the loop, and work out what effect the code should have on the system state (calls, etc).

A JIT compiler only looks at the bytecode *once*<sup>1</sup>, and compiles it to native code which can then be understood directly by the computer - no further translation required. The translation takes time, so if you can do it just the once, it's more efficient.

To give a real world example: if you had a novel in English, and some French people who were interested in it, you *could* give the book to someone who knew both languages, who could read it aloud to each person individually. Or, you could get that person to take the book away, translate it into French, and then give each French person a copy of the book in French. If only one person is interested in the book, then the on-the-fly translation is more efficient - no need for a copy-editor, layout specialist, printer etc... but if you've got lots of people who want to read the book, then doing a more thorough one-off translation 
makes more sense.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some JITs, including the one in HotSpot, will actually JIT-compile the same code several times with different levels of optimization, depending on use.

Comment: I like the novel example you gave. About the HotSpot comment, I assume that JIT-compile the same code several times could be a bottle neck when executing the program, can it? I wonder how fast a JIT-compiler v.s an "ahead-of-time" compiler when compiling the codes?

Comment: @tsubasa: It will only recompile it when the JIT has spotted that it *is* causing a bottleneck, and judged that it's likely to be worth spending some more time optimizing. There are lots of subtleties there, and occasionally it will get it wrong, of course, but it's generally good :)

Comment: +1 The novel example seems like a *great* metaphor for interpretation VS compilation in general (the sole difference between JIT and AOT is that AOT publishers translate the books before even selling one, while JIT publishers wait and see which translations would probably sell).

Comment: @JonSkeet: +1 In addition to your point, I think all programs in IL (e.g. bytecode) can only be optimized to some extent because of their inherent higher level of abstraction. I mean because java bytecodes are not designed for an specific architecture, they cannot be optimized to a great level. As a result, the interpreter should interpret a code that is not optimized well. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The JIT-compiled code is actually running directly on the bare metal whereas interpreted code has to be continually reinterpreted by the interpreter. The interpreter is no longer having to reprocess and reprocess the byte code.